# Removing layout exits my application

Tags: android, android-layout

I have this code for initial/default layout

```
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
    WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
      // Retrieve the shared preferences
    mGameSettings = getSharedPreferences(GAME_PREFERENCES, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

    glView = new GLSurfaceView(this);
    glView.setRenderer(this);
    glView.setZOrderMediaOverlay(false);
    glView.setId(123); // set id 

    layout = new RelativeLayout(this);
    // create a fake view with zero size and place it to center of RelativeLayout
    fakeView = new View(this); 
    fakeView.setId(24736); 
    fakeparams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(0, 0);
    fakeparams.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_IN_PARENT, RelativeLayout.TRUE);

    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
    params.addRule(RelativeLayout.ABOVE, fakeView.getId()); // set position is above fakeView
    layout.addView(glView, params);

    setContentView(layout);
```

Say we are in main menu and in some menu when user click it, i'll inflate new layout which I prepared in res/layout folder

```
    myStoryView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.story2, layout, false);
    layout.addView(myStoryView);
```

This goes well, I get the result, new layout appear as it should. 
later I call this code when user want to close story screen and return to main menu:

```
    layout.removeView(myStoryView);
```

But what happened is I lose all my layout. It exits entire app, though in my galaxy tab when I hold center button, I can see my app is there, maybe it's not entirely closed. I only have no layout to display.

Comment: try overriding onBackPressed() method with your desired result when back key is pressed

Comment: layout.removeView(myStoryView);  is actually the code i run on my backPressed. i don't have problem with backpressed.

Comment: can you post onBackPressed method here?

Comment: <code> @Override
     public void onBackPressed() {
      if (FLAG_GAME_ACTIVITY == true) { //false = in game pause
       super.pauseGame(); 
      } else if (FLAG_GAME_STORYMENU == true) {
          layout.removeView(myStoryView);
       
      } else super.onBackPressed();
      
         //do nothing
     } </code>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

sorry, i just need to

```
setContentView(layout)
```